# Convert images to PDF file using PDFBox

Tags: java, pdf-generation, pdfbox

I want to convert some images to `PDDocument` object, and not save to hardware. How to get input stream from this `PDDocument` object?

I wrote as below, got "Create InputStream called without data being written before to stream." error.

The part of source is:

```
public ByteArrayOutputStream imagesToPdf(final List<ImageEntity> images) throws IOException {
    final PDDocument doc = new PDDocument();
    
    final int count = images.size();
    InputStream in = null;
    PDPageContentStream contentStream = null;
    final ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    try {
        for (int i = 0; i < count; i ++) {
            final ImageEntity image = images.get(i);
            byte[] byteCode = image.getByteCode();

            in = new ByteArrayInputStream(byteCode);
            BufferedImage bi = ImageIO.read(in);

            float width = bi.getWidth();
            float height = bi.getHeight();
            PDPage page = new PDPage(new PDRectangle(width, height));
            doc.addPage(page); 

            PDImageXObject pdImage = PDImageXObject.createFromByteArray(doc, byteCode, null);
            contentStream = new PDPageContentStream(doc, page, AppendMode.APPEND, true, true);
            
            float scale = 1f;
            contentStream.drawImage(pdImage, 0, 0, pdImage.getWidth()*scale, pdImage.getHeight()*scale);
            
            IOUtils.closeQuietly(contentStream);
            IOUtils.closeQuietly(in);
        }

        PDStream ps = new PDStream(doc);
        is = ps.createInputStream();
        IOUtils.copy(is, baos);

        return baos;
    } finally {
        IOUtils.closeQuietly(contentStream);
        IOUtils.closeQuietly(in);
    }
}
```

Comment: Great idea for converting multiple images to single pdf without physical storage. Awesome.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
new PDStream(doc)
```

does **not** create an object from which the `doc` can be retrieved in serialized form as you assume. What it actually does is create a PDF stream object *belonging to the document `doc`.*

What you want to do is simply

```
doc.save(baos);
```

Comment: @user1737352 Great! In that case please mark the answer as accepted (click the tick at its upper left).

Comment: sorry, I cannot click the triangle symbol at its upper left, due to my reputation is less than 15.

Comment: Beneath the two triangles there should be a tick symbol which you can toggle to be grey or green. 
The tick is for accepting, the triangles are for up or down voting.  Accepting should be possible for you as the one who asked the question, no matter what your reputation is.

Comment: Awesome. You have given good simple and correct idea.